# Parsing DOM information with XPath

Tags: selenium, dom, xpath

I want to parse the DOM (websites) for specific information, for example looking for certain strings that may be found in text nodes or attribute values. I am doing this using XPath. Both DOM and XPath use the XML structure of the document.

Is this a valid procedure, and does XPath operate on the same information that are located in the DOM? What differences are there between Using XPath, and parsing the DOM using some other way? (Which better alternatives would there be?)

I am currently using Selenium WebDriver with 'findElements(By.xpath(QUERY))' which is very convenient, but I wondered if I might overlook content that I am not aware of.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a useful [blog about locator stategies](https://blog.mozilla.org/webqa/2013/09/26/writing-reliable-locators-for-selenium-and-webdriver-tests/).

To sum it up: use id (`findElements(By.id("id"))`) whereever you can. If not, use CSS locators (`findElements(By.cssSelector("css"))`) . Xpath is considered to be the last resort.

Comment: Thanks! However, I am parsing unknown websites, so using the ID is not an option. I don't want to locate and re-use them, but rather I want to look for keywords. If these are not unique, no problem, i will simply return multiple matches. Your link goes in great depth regarding liability of locators, but I am rather interested in the similarities and differences between information in the DOM and the results of XPath requests. (Like can there be information in one, but not the other). Thank you for the reply though!